# "PROCEDURE ANALYSE" analogues in MySQL 8 and PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql

In older versions of `MySQL` there was an option to analyze existing tables:

```
SELECT * FROM  `table_name` PROCEDURE ANALYSE()
```

That seemed useful, a developer could analyze existing tables, see recommendations (for example use smallint instead of int) and consider some of them.

In MySQL 8.0 `PROCEDURE ANALYSE()` was removed. The reason I found:

> "Reasoning: it was discussed many times that the PROCEDURE ANALYZE
>   syntax is an anachronism and almost unused non-standard syntax
>   extension".

Is this the only reason or analyzing tables automatically is a bad practice (even as just an additional instrument for analyze)?

Also I can't find any analogue of `"Procedure Analyse"` in Postgresql.

I know that I can analyze queries, but I suppose that it is useful to analyze table structure to consider it in architecture of new tables.

Comment: Postgresql don,t have that.. Maybe about definition.. Mostly when make table you will know what you are going to input.. So it's rarely to use..

Comment: People often use INT when SMALLINT or even TINYINT is sufficient, don't use ENUM, TINYTEXT, and so on. We often do not know how large columns do we need. MySQL helped to analyse existing tables to avoid these problems. Maybe there are other instruments, I will look for them.

Comment: Really angered me to see this gone with no replacement provided, it was a great feature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is gone and no clear successor that I can find is provided or referenced in the documentation. I attempted to email the guy responsible for this, he no longer works at MySQL and his personal email is dead, so maybe his work was cut short. It's a shame they removed PROCEDURE ANALYSE that users relied on without providing a replacement stored procedure that they talked about.

One can analyse tables manually with statements such as:

```
select MAX(LENGTH(address1)) from places;
select address1 from places where length(address1) > 99;
```